# Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'. fault

Tags: java, android, gson, retrofit, rx-java

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso- 
 core:3.4.0'
    implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit: 2.9.1")
    implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson: 2.9.1")
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2: 2.9.1"
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxjava:3.1.5"
   implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxandroid:3.1.5"
   implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'
}
```

> and It gives me error (2022-08-15 09:49:02.807 11330-11330/? W/DetectPable: type=1400 audit(0.0:357906): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/proc/dma" dev="proc" ino=4026532069 scontext=u:r:shell:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:proc:s0 tclass=file permissive=0)
> in logcat.

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 8 column 1 path $ <- your service crashes and returns an error page instead of a json? Check your service via browser and see what's the problem.

Comment: My application is run but nothing see data. Could you describe more?

Comment: Please provide the relevant code snippets of your application.

Comment: Hi now I'm making an app from scratch. The first step is I added the Implementation and it gives this error.